# node.js - can't load css when param express.js too long

Tags: css, node.js, express, parameters, ejs

I'm writting a application by Node.js,express.js,ejs....

I'm using this code to use ejs and load css:

```
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
```

This is my dir struct

```
myapp
--Controller
----admin.js
--db
----db.js
--views
----admin
------user.html
------addUser.html
----css
------style.css
--app.js
```

Html load css like this

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And i had used css for my web. when i use params :

```
app.get('/admin/users', admin.users);
app.get('/admin/add', admin.add);
```

url are:

> loocalhost:1080/admin/users
>
> loocalhost:1080/admin/add

then **my css active**. but when i use param:

```
app.get('/admin/users/add', admin.add);
```

url is:

> loocalhost:1080/admin/users/add

then **my css not active.**

so how to fix it??
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid making your CSS links relative. So specify them like so:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```